# Magento - Create URL to search products only by manufacturer

Tags: php, magento, search

I'm very newbie with Magento.

My customer requests some edits to the Magento Search Engine to retrieve a list of products filtered by the manufacturer attribute.

Then, I was wondering if it was possible to create a predefined url to execute a search with standard Magento engine (Catalogsearch) to retrieve all products via the manufacturer name?

For example:

- http://mysite/?manufacturer=nike or
- http://mysite/catalogsearch/?manufacturer=nike

Clicking on this link the user can see the standard list of retrieved products of the template but filtered by manufacturer (and not filtered by name).

Please, can you help me?

Comment: this will serve your request http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/shop-by-brand-manufacturer-free-extension.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I've seen the extension but I need to create predefined URLs to set the href attribute in my <a> tag for a more quickly search. When my user  clicks on a brand logo, he will be redirected to the default magento search page but with all filtered products by brand. (I've already set the Manufacturer attribute to my all products). For this reason I need a predefined URL.

Comment: @CeccoCQ have you found the answer. I am looking for exact same brands page?